Do I need properties for passing parameters to a Gradle plugin?
I am writing a Gradle plugin. What is the recommended way to pass parameters to it?
The Writing Custom Gradle Plugins Baeldung tutoral (section 4, "Plugin Configuration") recommends creating a MyPluginExtension class that would contain all necessary data. (See the link, it shows how they create an extension object and use it from Gradle DSL.)
Now, I have seen some discussion about properties (like Property<String>), task parameters should be all done using properties, not sure about plugin parameters.
I tried to look at what existing code does. Well, there is a lot of modern code that does not use properties.
And now, in the docs for CheckstyleExtension I see a mix of properties and raw types:
DirectoryProperty configDirectory
Property<Boolean> enableExternalDtdLoad
boolean ignoreFailures
int maxErrors
String toolVersion

So far my impression is that properties are not obligatory, but they at least do not harm, not sure if they do any good.

Should plugin parameters be properties? What do exactly these properties do, are they meaningful for plugins? (Plugins define new tasks and/or modify existing tasks.)

If there is another way to pass parameters to a plugin (configure it), please tell me about it too.




I am writing a Gradle plugin. What is the recommended way to pass parameters to it?

Yes, absolutely use Property types inside an extension.
The primary reason for the Property types is lazy configuration1. It allows those properties to be modified at any time during the project configuration phase2, and the plugin (or other code which creates tasks based on the value of those properties) to always know it accesses the modified version of those properties.
Now this isn't a problem if there is a single plugin which specifies a non-lazy property which that plugin only uses at task execution time. But if another user wants to write a second plugin which wants to do something at configuration time based on what the end user specifies for the property, that second plugin can't easily know what the end configuration of that value is.
This is potentially the beginning of afterEvaluate hell, where plugins run code in such hooks at the end of the configuration phase in order to attempt to capture the final version of such properties. But if such hooks also modify other properties further, programmers may end up with the unenviable debugging task of trying to figure out the order afterEvaluate hooks run.
The Property and Provider interfaces elegantly navigate such problems.
So, in other words: yes a plugin can potentially "get away" with not using Property types in certain situations. However, it is best practice to use them as it makes your plugin maximally useable and extensible for future plugin authors and for future modifications of your own plugin.

1 See Gradle discussion of lazy configuration
2 See Gradle discussion of the build lifecycle
